# Is it possible to have specific italic or bold text in UWP notifications?

Tags: c#, uwp, notifications

I'm working on a UWP app that creates notifications in C# by using the UWP Community Toolkit, and it would be useful to have italic or bold text in the notification body. I don't want the entire notification to be formatted this way, nor do I want to add another AdaptiveText to the notification. I just want specific pieces of text to be italic or bold.

I've already looked at [Toast content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts) and [AdaptiveText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-schema#adaptivetext), which imply that it's not possible, but never say so outright. I have also searched Stack Overflow, but didn't find any questions about this issue. **Is this possible in the UWP?**

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

The only way, if I am not mistaken, is to add an header to the notification template.
That’s all.

Comment: I was thinking that it's not possible, but I'm looking for some hard proof one way or the other. If you can find anything, I would accept. However, I'm not looking for headers, either, because they just add an entire bold line and do not bold specific text.

Comment: @TemporaryIdentity    At this time, there is no way to customize text appearance in UWP notification.  Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there are at least 2 ways to make text bold, read the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.fontweights

Comment: He was asking about making bold or italic text in *Toast Notifications*, not in regular XAML.

Comment: toast notofication is very similler to XML, as you can see here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast

it is worth trying

Comment: It doesn’t mean nothing, you can only insert some very simplified control, as you can see in your own link.  For text element , you can control only the number of text lines, which can be up to 4.  That’s it.

Comment: I agree with @LucaLindholm that this wasn't what I was looking for. AdaptiveText seems to be a pretty restrictive class, so the FontWeights class doesn't work with it.